# Convert collect-map-foreach scala code block to spark/sql library functions

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark dataframe (let's call it "records") like the following one:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| a1 | john |
| b"2 | alice |
| c3' | joe |

If you notice, the primary key column (id) values may have single/double quotes in them (like the second and third row in the dataframe).

I wrote following scala code to check for quotes in primary key column values:

```
def checkForQuotesInPrimaryKeyColumn(primaryKey: String, records: DataFrame): Boolean = {
  // Extract primary key column values
  val pkcValues = records.select(primaryKey).collect().map(_(0)).toList
  // Check for single and double quotes in the values
  var checkForQuotes = false // indicates no quotes
  breakable {
    pkcValues.foreach(pkcValue => {
    if (pkcValue.toString.contains("\"") || pkcValue.toString.contains("\'")) {
      checkForQuotes = true
      println("Value that has quotes: " + pkcValue.toString)
      break()
    }
  })}
  checkForQuotes
}
```

This code works. But it doesn't take advantage of spark functionalities. I wish to make use of spark executors (and other features) that can complete this task faster.

The updated function looks like the following:

```
def checkForQuotesInPrimaryKeyColumnsUpdated(primaryKey: String, records: DataFrame): Boolean = {
  val findQuotes = udf((s: String) => if (s.contains("\"") || s.contains("\'")) true else false)
  records
    .select(findQuotes(col(primaryKey)) as "quotes")
    .filter(col("quotes") === true)
    .collect()
    .nonEmpty
}
```

The unit tests give similar runtimes on my machine for both the functions when run on a dataframe with 100 entries.

Is the updated function any faster (and/or better) than the original function? Is there any way the function can be improved?

Answer (score 1):

Your first approach collects the entire dataframe to the driver. If your data does not fit into the driver's memory, it is going to break. Also you are right, you do not take advantage of spark.

The second approach uses spark to detect quotes. That's better. The problem is that you then collect a dataframe containing one boolean per record containing a quote to the driver just to see if there is at least one. This is a waste of time, especially if many records contain quotes. It is also a shame to use a UDF for this, since they are known to be slower than spark SQL primitives.

You could simply use spark to count the number records containing a quote, without collecting anything.

```scala
records.where(col(primaryKey).contains("\"") || col(primaryKey).contains("'"))
     .count > 0
```

Since, you do not actually care about the number of records. You just want to check if there is at least one, you could use `limit(1)`. SparkSQL will be able to further optimize the query:

```scala
records.where(col(primaryKey).contains("\"") || col(primaryKey).contains("'"))
    .limit(1).count > 0
```

NB: it makes sense that in unit tests, with little data, both of your queries take the same time. Spark is meant for big data and has some overhead. With real data, your second approach should be faster than the first and the one I propose even so. Also, your first approach will get an OOM on the driver as soon as you add in more data.